# 3.7v to 12v or 24v amp calculation

Tags: power-supply, batteries, current

I'm trying to connect some 18250 lithium ion battery. 3.7v and has a 2700mAh capacity. I'll like to connect twenty of the batteries which I guess will be 54A at 3.7v in series to boost the valtage to 12v or 24v. My question is how much Amp will the twenty batteries derive in both 12v and 24v connections. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect 1 to a million 2700mAh batteries in series you’ll still have 2700mAh but the voltage will differ. In terms of actual Amps you can draw depends on the batteries themselves. You’ll need to look in the datasheet for this.